# How to install a package from git into a specific directory using pip -t

Tags: python, linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pip

I have downloaded all of my requirements in `AWS Linux + EFS` using

```
pip3 install -t /mnt/efs/fs1/ml/ -r /mnt/efs/fs1/ml/requirements.txt
```

They get downloaded without an issue and I'm able to call them too. Now I want to [install detectron2](https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/install.html#build-detectron2-from-source) but it has to be done separately as it requires `torch` already in the system.

I install it with:

```
pip3 install -t /mnt/efs/fs1/ml/ 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git'
```

Even if I have installed `torch` in above requirements, and able to import it too. I also installed it in the global path too (without `-t`) but still I'm getting the error:

```
pip3 install 'git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git'
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting git+https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git
  Cloning https://github.com/facebookresearch/detectron2.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-bcthhh9q
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-bcthhh9q/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-req-build-bcthhh9q/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-nmaxo6d1
         cwd: /tmp/pip-req-build-bcthhh9q/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-req-build-bcthhh9q/setup.py", line 10, in <module>
        import torch
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'torch'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

What is the problem here? The below command runs perfectly in my system when I don't install `requirements.txt` with `-t` flag.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like version issue, version supported for torch and detectron2 should be in sync.You can go through this for details :

https://detectron2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/install.html

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. The `PYTHONPATH` was pointing to default directory so had to tell the `env` about the new location of packages.

All you have to do is to  run the command in terminal:

```
export PYTHONPATH="${PYTHONPATH}:/mnt/efs/fs1/ml"
```

And then use the command as usual. It'll work fine